# How to perform lrange + (delete the result of lrange from list) on Redis list

Tags: caching, redis

I am aware that rpop removes the last element of the Redis list.How to pop items of list between certain range (eg: 0 to 100)?

I hope this is the combination of lrange + rpop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine **lrange** and **ltrim** to achieve this.

http://redis.io/commands/ltrim

**Edit :** 
As suggested in the comments the right answer is

```
lrange list 0 99
ltrim list 100 -1
```

Comment: Is only ltrim not enough?

Comment: Ltrim's reply is just OK. if you want the values you need lrange, after getting that you can issue ltrim to remove them from the list. Combine them in a lua to make it atomic

Comment: That is incorrect on several levels. First to get first 100 items you want to do `LRANGE list 0 99`, then there is the thing that LTRIM does oposite of what you say, it leaves the first 100 items and deletes everything else. If you want to delete first 100 items you would need to do `LTRIM list 100 -1` (i.e. leave everything starting with item 100)

But more importantly, this is very unsafe as this operation is not atomic, so the list may be changed between first and second statement - you will need to figure out how to make it atomic

Comment: @mlasevich Is transaction a good way to go to avoid this inconsistency about not being atomic?

Answer (score 13):

To select and remove the first 100 elements (from the left):

```
LRANGE list 0 99
LTRIM list 100 -1
```

To select and remove the last 100 elements (from the right):

```
LRANGE list -1 -100
LTRIM list 0 -99
```

From an older version of the redis documentation for [`LTRIM`](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim):

> Trim the list `name`, removing all values not within the slice between `start` and `end`.
> `start` and `end` can be negative numbers just like Python slicing notation

Comment: Is this the safe against race conditions?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no predefined command to pop a range of items from a list.
You have to send a series of rpop commands to redis.
It's usual with Redis to send many short commands, so it's not a problem to send 100 (or even 1000) rpop commands in a row.
To improve performances you can send multiple command in one operation using "pipelining". The exact way of doing this depends on your driver.

Another way would be to write a Lua script and send it using [eval](http://redis.io/commands/eval)

Answer (score 2):

remove the first top 100 element,should be:

lrange list 0 99 
ltrim list 100 -1

remove the tail top 100 element,should be:

lrange list -100 -1 
ltrim list 0 -101

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for me, this does. I'm talking about the reverse option, `lrange list -100 -1 ltrim list 0 -101`.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but if you want to do everything atomically, you can use the multi/exec commands.

#### An example for reading and removing two elements.

1. Prepare some dummy data for the sake of example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> rpush mylist 1 2 3 4
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange mylist 0 -1
1) "1"
2) "2"
3) "3"
4) "4"
```

2. Start a transaction block

```
127.0.0.1:6379> multi
OK
```

3. Queue the needed commands (read the first two elements and remove them).

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange mylist 0 1
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379> ltrim mylist 2 -1
QUEUED
```

4. Execute the commands

```
127.0.0.1:6379> exec
1) 1) "1"
   2) "2"
2) OK
```

5. Verify everything went well. Again, just for the sake of example.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange mylist 0 -1
1) "3"
2) "4"
```